# Building ANT Task through Jenkins with SASS

Tags: ant, jenkins, sass, task

I have an ANT task where it calls a SASS cmd.

This works properly in eclipse, but when I try to call that Ant task through Jenkins, it says "It could not find sass...(Gem::LoadError)"

I have the jenkins process running as 'root'.

Comment: Can you run the Ant task successfully from the command line as root?

Comment: Hmm. Didn't test that just yet, but I noticed that it's trying to execute: /usr/bin/sass but the sass that works is executed: /usr/local/bin/sass